# Atualizar valor usando For a cada evento

Tags: javascript, html, for

eu estou com este codigo aqui:

```js
var current  = 0;
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10];

function aparecer(){
 //verifica se o current é maior do que o array
 if ( (array1.length - 1) < current ) {
  alert("oi");
  //isso deveria parar a função
  return false;
 }
 for (var i= current; i <= (current + 2); i++){
  const lugar = document.getElementById('local');

  const ul    = document.createElement('UL');
  const valor = document.createTextNode(array1[i])
  ul.appendChild(valor);

  lugar.appendChild(ul);

 } 
 current = i;
}

function desaparecer(){
 current = 0;
 document.getElementById('local').innerHTML= '';
  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <button onClick='aparecer()'> Aparecer </button>
  
  <button onClick='desaparecer()'> Desaparecer </button>
  
  <div id='local'> </div>
  
</html>
```

E a cada clique eu quero atualizar o valor 1,2,3, para 4,5,6, assim sucessivamente e nao acrescentar na tela novamente.

Alguem pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes do `for`, esvazie a `div` com `document.getElementById('local').innerHTML= '';`:

```js
var current  = 0;
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10];

function aparecer(){
 //verifica se o current é maior do que o array
 if ( (array1.length - 1) < current ) {
  alert("oi");
  //isso deveria parar a função
  return false;
 }
       document.getElementById('local').innerHTML= '';
 for (var i= current; i <= (current + 2); i++){
  const lugar = document.getElementById('local');

  const ul    = document.createElement('UL');
  const valor = document.createTextNode(array1[i])
  ul.appendChild(valor);

  lugar.appendChild(ul);

 } 
 current = i;
}

function desaparecer(){
 current = 0;
 document.getElementById('local').innerHTML= '';
  
}
```

```html
<button onClick='aparecer()'> Aparecer </button>
  
  <button onClick='desaparecer()'> Desaparecer </button>
  
  <div id='local'> </div>
```

Comment: Nossa mano, que boa dica kkkkk.Obrigadao