# Como atualizar um elemento com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, for

eu estou com este codigo:

```js
let inicial = -0;
const numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function proximo (){ 
       inicial++
       document.getElementById("lugar").innerHTML=''

       alert(inicial)
    
    for(let i = inicial-1; i < inicial+2; i++){
        const ul           = document.createElement('UL');
        const numerosUl    = document.createTextNode(numeros[i]);
        const lugarElement = document.getElementById("lugar");
      
        ul.appendChild(numerosUl);
      
        lugarElement.appendChild(ul);
    }
}


function limpar(){
  document.getElementById("lugar").innerHTML=''
}
```

```html
<html>
  <button onClick="proximo()"> Próximo </button>
  <div id="lugar">  Teste </div>
  
  
  <button onClick="limpar()"> Limpar </html>
</html>
```

Ele está aparecendo em 3 em 3 numeros, porem, eu quero que, a cada clique ele atualize ele mesmo com os proprios numeros do array em sequencia.

**Exemplo:** Se clicar agora, vai aparecer 1,2,3. Eu quero que quando clicar na proxima vez, apareça: 4,5,6 e no proximo: 7,8,9 e no ultimo clique, apareça: 10. Nao criando novos elementos no body e sim atualizando-o.

Alguem poderia me ajudar e se possivel explicar o que foi feito? 
Quero apenas esta mudanca, de comecar do numero que nao aparece na tela, que logo de inicio é, 1 ate 3, e comecar do 4 e ir ate 6 e comecar do 7 e ir ate o 9 e quando clicar pelo ultima vez aparecer o 10.

Comment: Qual é a diferença desta dúvida para a da sua [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277378/atualizar-valor-usando-for-a-cada-evento)? A resposta lá não resolveu o problema?

Comment: @bfavaretto não, ele 'comia' o numero 7. N sei por que.

E o numero 10 deveria aparecer sozinho, e por o numero 7 nao aparecer, ele aparecia junto ao 9

Comment: Ok, entendi. Mas você podia ter comentado isso na própria resposta do @dvd na outra pergunta, tenho certeza que ele iria rever o código. Quando você marca a resposta como aceita (tick verde), como fez lá, fica parecendo que o problema está resolvido.

Comment: Sim, eu nem tinha reparado foi meu amigo que viu, mas me ajudou aquele codigo, compreendi algumas coisas

Comment: Uma outra coisa pra ficar atento, que só uma das respostas abaixo corrige: você está gerando HTML inválido, não pode inserir um text node direto no UL. Precisa de um LI em volta do text node, e o LI sim vai dentro no UL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize um `for` simples e dentro do `for` utilize `if (!numeros[inicial]) break;`. Dessa forma a repetição será interrompida caso não encontre um valor válido.

```js
let inicial = 0;
const numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const lugarElement = document.querySelector("#lugar ul");

function proximo() {

  /* Limpa a tela caso ainda possua números a serem exibidos */
  if (inicial < numeros.length)
    lugarElement.innerHTML = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (!numeros[inicial]) break;

    /* Adiciona o LI dentro do UL */
    lugarElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", `<li>${numeros[inicial]}</li>`);

    inicial++;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="proximo()"> Próximo </button>
<div id="lugar"><ul></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    let inicial = 0; 
const numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function proximo (){ for(let i = 0; i <= 3; i++){ 

    if(numeros[inicial] != null){

        const ul           = document.createElement('UL');
        const numerosUl    = document.createTextNode(numeros[inicial]);
        const lugarElement = document.getElementById("lugar");
        inicial++;

        ul.appendChild(numerosUl);

        lugarElement.appendChild(ul);
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho bom avisar que não pode pendurar um text node diretamente numa UL.

Answer (score 1):

Para um código simples desse, eu nem usaria o `for`:

```js
var inicial = 0;
var numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var lugar = document.getElementById('lugar');

var ul = lugar.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
var li1 = ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
var li2 = ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
var li3 = ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));

function proximo() {
  if ((inicial + 1) > numeros.length)
    // se já acabaram os números do array, saia da função
    return;
   
   // se já acabaram os índices do array, o valor é esvaziado
   li1.textContent = numeros[inicial++] || "";
   li2.textContent = numeros[inicial++] || "";
   li3.textContent = numeros[inicial++] || "";
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <button onClick="proximo()"> Próximo </button>
  <div id="lugar"> </div>
</html>
```

Mas se no seu caso for ter mais de 3 itens, fica inviável criar todos os `<li>`s individualmente. Caso precise usar o `for`, as respostas acima são suficientes, mas com um adendo:

## Nunca atualize o DOM dentro de um `for`

Essa é uma [péssima prática para performance](https://tableless.com.br/jquery-dicas-de-otimizacao-e-performance/#6-dom) (o artigo fala sobre o jQuery, mas a dica é geral).

Então, caso for utilizar de um loop, altere como HTML, com todos os itens juntos:

```
...
function proximo() {
    ...
    var html = '';
    for(...) {
        html += '<li>' + (numeros[inicial++] || "") + '</li>';
    }
    ul.innerHTML = html;
...
}
```

Comment: Sua dica é boa. Porém acredito que se o o último appendChild (que de fato insere coisas na página) ficasse após o `for`, não haveria problemas.

Comment: O problema é que seu código fica restrito. E se em vez de 10 números fossem 100?

Comment: @bfavaretto haveriam problemas porque, diferente do jQuery, `Node.appendChild` não aceita um array de elementos. @dvd sim sim, por isso deixei claro que se forem mais de três itens (ou quantidade variável), usar o `for` mesmo, mas com aquela correção.

Comment: Eu quis dizer que montar toda a lista no for não tem problema enquanto o UL não tiver pai. Só o appendChild do UL na div que vai causar um reflow.

Comment: Aaah, realmente!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer desta forma, adicionando os elementos de uma vez sem usar `createElement`.

> Note que o código abaixo irá inserir apenas 1 `<ul>` com suas devidas
>   `<li>`, que é o correto, e não várias `<ul>` como sugere seu código.

```js
let inicial = 0;
const numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function proximo (){ 

   if(inicial >= numeros.length) return; // sai da função caso "iniciar" seja maior ou igual ao número de itens na array

   document.getElementById("lugar").innerHTML=''; // esvazia a div

   var els = '';
   for(let i = inicial; i <= inicial+2; i++){
      if(numeros[i]){ // somente se houver algum valor   
         els += '<li>'+numeros[i]+'</li>'; // concateno os novos elementos
      }
   }

   document.getElementById("lugar").innerHTML = "<ul>"+els+"</ul>";
   inicial += 3; // aumento o valor em +3
}

function limpar(){
    document.getElementById("lugar").innerHTML=''; // esvazia a div
}
```

```html
<button onClick="proximo()"> Próximo </button>
<div id="lugar"></div>
<button onClick="limpar()"> Limpar </button>
```

Comment: Essa lista aí já tem outra estrutura, né? Uma UL para cada item?

Comment: Realmente... se bem que o código da pergunta sugere isso... vou arrumar